# What does it means to be "X whisper"?

Tags: meaning

I came across this headline:

"Should Biden Run in 2024? Democratic Whispers of ‘No’ Start to Rise."

in the Whispers of ‘No’ OR I belive is the same: the ‘No’ Whispers what is the meaning of
Whispers??

Comment: Did you look up 'whisper' (noun) in a dictionary?

Comment: Horse / dog / cat whisperer is someone who is skilled in training animals who do not obey or spontaneously cooperate with their owners for whatever reason be it psychological or physical. https://www.lexico.com/definition/horse_whisperer

Answer (score 1):

*Democratic Whispers of ‘No’ Start to Rise*. means:

There are democratic whispers of the answer to the question "Should Biden Run in 2024". These whispers are the word: no.

whisper is speaking in a low voice, rather than a normal or a loud one.

In other words, one can hear people saying in low voices (whispers) that no, he should not run in the next election.

Comment: do the same apply to "Dog whipers"??

Comment: @guerdoosinfu I think you mean: dog **whisperer**.

Comment: you're right! do that differ from my original example which is: " Whispers of ‘No’"? I mean the concept?

Comment: I understand it to mean that members of Mr Biden's own party, the Democrats, are beginning to say discreetly that he ought not to run for office again. This has nothing to do with an [animal] whisperer, who tames that kind of animal by talking quietly to it.

Comment: @KateBunting Of course, Democratic whispers means the Democrats.

Comment: @guerdoosinfu Please write this down: Does that differ from my original example. Yes, it does. A whisperer is someone who talks softly  and recently we've seen dog whisperer and horse whisperer, here and there.

Comment: @Lambie, got yhis. Thanks. Kate Bunting  , got your poit of viwe al well

Comment: @Lambie - I only put that comment in because I thought it might not be obvious to a non-American that the political party was meant.